# How to console input from a class in java like that of cpp

Tags: java, methods, console

How to console input data in java class(not main class). The input methods work in cpp but not in java. Is there a way to console from a class method. System.in.read and interger parse methods are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Scanner with System.in

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int x = input.nextInt();

String t = input.next();

like wise

Try following code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {


 public static void main (String [] args){

    A a = new A();

    a.getValue();


 }

}

class A {

    public void getValue(){


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number : ");

        int x = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(x);


        }



    }
```

Comment: Does scanner work in a created class(for example cin in cpp works as an object to input data from console. But input methods like systm.in.read and parse doesn't work inside a class methods.. The input should be derived inside the main class. But cpp can create inside any other class. Does scanner work like that.

Comment: Thank you mate for this valuable help.